# NSInternalInconsistency Exception - findPlaylistByID is Invalid - What does that mean?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am catching an error in XCode 4 without making any changes.  A screen shot of the error is attached and here is the code that I am suspecting is causing the issue.  Please help me out if you can, I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
e- (void)fetchVideoInfoForPlaylist:(id)aDict {
BrightcoveDemoAppDelegate *delegate = (BrightcoveDemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
BCMediaAPI *bc = delegate.bcServices;
PlaylistCacheObject *playlistCacheObj;
BCPlaylist *playlist = (BCPlaylist *)[aDict objectForKey:PLAYLIST_DICT_KEY];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[aDict objectForKey:CELL_DICT_KEY];
NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithLong:playlist.playlistId];

if ([playlistCache objectForKey:key]) {
    playlistCacheObj = [playlistCache objectForKey:key];
}
else {
    // request, stash in cache
    NSError *err;
    playlist = [bc findPlaylistById:playlist.playlistId videoFields:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"thumbnailURL",nil] playlistFields:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"videos", @"thumbnailURL",nil] customFields:nil error:&err];
    if (!playlist) {
        [[ErrorHandlerService sharedInstance] logMediaAPIError:err];
    } 
    else if (playlist.videos && [playlist.videos count] > 0) {
        [playlist.videos objectAtIndex:0];

        // fetch the thumbnai for the first video
        NSString *imageURL = [playlist thumbnailURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]]; 
        playlistCacheObj = [[[PlaylistCacheObject alloc] initWithData:playlist image:image] autorelease];
    [playlistCache setObject:playlistCacheObj forKey:key];  ;   }   

    }
```

[image: CRASH LOG SCREENCAP]

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is being thrown from `BCPlaylistReadService`, not `PlaylistTableViewController`. I suspect there's an `NSAssert` in there. I would guess from this that either `playlist` or `playlist.playlistId` is `nil`, but alternately `playlist.playlistId` might just be invalid as the assertion notes.

Comment: How do you suggest I handle the NSAssert?

Comment: I never changed any code, could this be due to upgrading Xcode and iOS?

Comment: You are passing something incorrect. Likely either playlist or playlist.playistId is nil. You handle the NSAssert by fixing the bug in your code that it is complaining about.